# Angular 8 generating c.querySelectorAll is not a function on click event in multiple places

Tags: angular8

My code works as expected, but the browser is generating the following error on every click:

```
content_script_bundle.js:16 Uncaught TypeError: c.querySelectorAll is 
not a function at MutationObserver.<anonymous> (content_script_bundle.js:16)
```

This is an example of the markup:

```
<mat-icon (click)="newEmployee()">control_point</mat-icon>
```

This is the method:

```
newEmployee() {
   this.employee = {id: null, title: '', firstname: '', lastname: '', phoneno: '', email: ''};
   this.msg = 'New employee';
   this.hideEditForm = !this.hideEditForm;
}
```

As mentioned I have other clicks in the app that generate the same error. Any ideas to point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

A colleague ran into this earlier, except with a VueJS based application.
Turns out it was a chrome browser extension, an ad-blocker one to be specific. Try the browser's incognito mode without extensions to determine whether it is the case or not, and if that appears to resolve the issue then in regular mode try disable one extension at a time to determine the culprit.

Comment: Right on the money! Ghostery an ad blocking extension was the culprit. Thanks!